# HTML showing the code as text instead of doing the function

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I'm new to making websites, only got some notions of C++. So I have this code 
in HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/Coin/wp-content/uploads/custom-css-js/77.js "></script>

<p>Click the button to trigger a function ".</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Generate question</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<div id="quote"></div>

<script>
function myFunction() 
{
        document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = showquote;               
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And this in JavaScript:

```
var myArray = ['Question 1', 'Test2', 'Practise 3'];
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);

function showquote(){
    document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = myArray[rand];
                    }
showquote();
```

When the button is clicked, this line appears:

```
function showquote(){ document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = myArray[rand]; }
```

As I said, I'm just trying things in this languaje I barely know about, am I not invoking the function right? Thanks in advance.

Comment: because `document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = showquote;` it assigns the function to the innerHTML.... also makes zero sense why you are trying to call the function, but it does not return anything but undefined and the function itsself assigns the innerHTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function myFunction() 
{
        document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = showquote;               
}
```

should be

```
function myFunction() 
{
        showquote();               
}
```

Click [**here** for an executable demo of the solution above](http://jsbin.com/rajehekara/edit?html,js,output).

## Reasoning

When you do

```
document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = showquote;
```

You are assigning to the inner HTML the source code of the `showquote` function. Which is why you get `function showquote(){ document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = myArray[rand]; }` (the source code of `showquote`) shown in the page.

So, what you really want to do is just call the `showquote` function, because that function alters the HTML alone. Thus the correct expression being `showquote()`, which invokes the `showcode` function.

## Other improvements

Since now your `myFunction` is just a call to  `showquote`:

```
function myFunction() 
{
        showquote();               
}
```

Then  you could actually remove it and use `showquote` directly in the `HTML` element.

```
<button onclick="showquote()">Generate question</button>
```

Another thing is, inside your JavaScript file, your first invocation of `showquote`, right after its declaration, in here:

```
function showquote() {
      document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = myArray[rand];
}
showquote(); // <----- this is the invocation I'm talking about
```

Is goint to yield an error. Simply because its code tries to find the element with `id` = `quote` (here: `document.getElementById('quote')`) and at the point this JavaScript code is executing, such element does not exist yet. Thus you getting an error at that point.

The solution is here is maybe just not call `showquote` at all. Or call it in a `<script>` tag right near the bottom of the HTML page, somewhere after the `quote` element is declared.

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I needed, the reasoning behind it, most of the time I find myself copying code and trying to adapt it to my program by commenting on functions and what they do but this time I simply had no idea where to start, your response was awesome and fast!